# How do I resolve issue with deleted table in SQL Server Database Diagrams?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I am working on a database design using the SQL Server Database Diagram tool.  I created a table with the name dbo.Example and before defining any columns, attempted to save.

Got an error that SQL can't save a table without any columns and as I wanted to save the other work I had done before completing this table, I deleted it and saved successfully.

I then make many more changes and save the diagram.  All is good.

UNTIL I am ready to correctly define my dbo.Example table and get the

```
'Table 'dbo.Example' already exists' error.
```

The table is not among the tables returned from

```
select name from sys.tables;
```

and does not appear in the Database->Tables GUI view.

I can't find where I need to clean up and drop this table.

Where does SQL Server keep the metadata about the database diagrams?

Comment: are you sure you use "Delete Tables From Database" option and not "Remove From Diagram" ? and that you checking against right Database ?

Comment: just for a note the diagrams are saved in SELECT * FROM sysdiagrams

Comment: Everything about the diagram is encapsulated in a binary field that only Management Studio knows how to serialize (see [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50593/2718)) -- have you tried closing and reopening the diagram?

Comment: @JonSeigel - thanks, this resolved my issue! My question is possibly a duplicate of your link, despite the difference in details.  I will edit so this can be answer...

Comment: `I am working on a database design using the SQL Server Database Diagram tool.` Maybe stop right there. I think the diagram tool is much better at reverse engineering than designing. YMMV.

Comment: @aaronbertrand I agree completely, but have only Visio 2012 (which has basically removed this functionality) and I am working in an environment which can't / won't pay for ERwin and can't use open source tools.  Have you any suggestions for a design tool?

Comment: FWIW, I use Visio to design, and then code all the SQL stuff by hand based on the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Management Studio.

I was able to reproduce it three ways, on both 2008 R2 and 2012 tools:

1. Create a new diagram; create a new empty table (any name); delete the table; in the same diagram, try to create a new table with the same name.
2. Create a new diagram; create a new empty table; delete the table; create a new diagram in the same database, and while the first one is still open, create a new table with the same name.
3. Create a new diagram; create a new empty table; delete the table; create a new diagram in the same database; close the first diagram; in the second diagram, create a new table with the same name.

From this behaviour, I'm guessing it keeps a list of tables per database outside the context of a single database diagram, and when an empty table is deleted, the reference isn't being cleaned up properly. I believe the fix is to close all diagrams for that database, and re-open. I think it's lucky you were able to save the changes you made with no errors!

I would suggest reporting this on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com) if you feel it's really important. IMO, it seems unlikely it will be fixed because it's so minor, but you never know.